# How to share information between parallel executions in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I would like to know if there is any way to transfer information between the parallel executions within one operator in Apache Flink during runtime? I just have to send a little messages. Broadcast variable in Flink does not work because it cannot broadcast during runtime.

Comment: You may need to be more specific about your use case, something like that should not be required under most circumstances. But if you can give more details maybe we can get to an approach that would work for what you need.

Comment: May be put that information into shared (inmemory) database and read from it?

Comment: @JoshuaDeWald Thanks. In my case, I would like to implement a streaming-based clustering algorithm in Flink. In my case the operator will have several parallel executions and each execution process a part of the stream data and can generate new centroids and clusters. However, the generation of new centroids is not so frequent and should be known to other parallel executions (they may also use these new centroids).

Comment: @JoshuaDeWald  A shared state can perfectly solve this problem but Flink does not have shared states among parallel executions even inside the same operator. So I would like to know if it is possible to build the communication between parallel executions.

Comment: This isn't possible as far as I know, parallel operators are intended to be completely independent each other from a state perspective. 

If you're able to generate the centroids more upstream such that it can be sent/broadcast/whatever to your parallel operations as they are come about is the more Flink-like way I think. 

I don't know enough about the algorithm in question to know if that makes sense in your case. This may fit into using the "iterative" streams as well, where you are feeding the centroids back in.

Answer (score 1):

Because Flink doesn't yet support both broadcast and keyed streams going to the same function (what is being called "side-input support"), it becomes a bit tricky to do what you want without external shared state. But I think it's possible, with iterations.

E.g. for k-means you have `<point, centroid id>` as your tuple, where input values have null for the centroid id. Partition by point to a custom FlatMap that outputs `<point, centroid id, distance>`. Then repartition by point and find the closest centroid. Output `<point, centroid id>`, then repartition by centroid id and process with custom Map that keeps track of centroid center point. Emit updated `<center point, centroid id>` and have this iterate back up to the top.

So the first custom FlatMap needs to handle a real point (with null centroid id) and a centroid (centroid point, centroid id) differently, where it adds centroids to its state, so it can calculate distances for any real points it receives.

Comment: Just a minor comment: Support for connecting a keyed and a broadcast stream will be added for Flink 1.5.0. However, this feature is not the same as side inputs, which are more about proper support for bounded streams.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, my mistake - I'd read Aljoscha's email about "broadcast inputs and broadcast state being a first step towards side inputs" as meaning they were the same thing, but that's clearly not the case.